# Spring resources folder

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a Maven project which use Spring . In this project have a folder called res(in src/main/webapp), which contain resources(css, images, js, etc.). This resources are called in JSP files.

My problem is this: I try to put an image logo.png on index.jsp:

```
<img src="/res/images/logo.png"/>
```

In page appear this: [Page Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnm6N.jpg)

Here is how my project look: [Tree project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7l3gy.jpg)

How can I access logo.png?

Comment: Add resource mapping

Comment: I tried this : <mvc:resources mapping="/res/**" location="/res/" /> , but still the same result

Answer (score 0):

Unless you deploy your webapp as the root webapp in your server, the path of the image is wrong. It should start with the context path of your application:

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/res/images/logo.png"/>
```

If you mapped the spring servlet to `/`, you also need to make these resources available, either by [enabling the default servlet](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-default-servlet-handler), or by mapping the resources as explained [in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-caching-static-resources)

Comment: I tried this : <mvc:resources mapping="/res/**" location="/res/" /> , but still the same result

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/folder_name/"/>`

and also i recommend use jstl taglib

For example add dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and in your jsp you can use this approach instead you default:

`<c:url value="src="images/logo.png"/>`

good luck